# How to use .after with .create_rectangle?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a program that draws rectangles on a canvas on at a time, and I want to use the .after function to stop them from being drawn (near) instantly.

Currently my (stripped down) code looks like this:

```
root = Tk()
gui = ttk.Frame(root, height=1000, width=1000)
root.title("Test GUI")    

rgb_colour = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (0, 0, 255)

def func(*args):
    for item in sorted_list:
        canvas.create_rectangle(xpos, ypos, xpos+10, ypos+10, fill=rgb_colour)
        xpos += 10

canvas = Canvas(gui, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.grid()

func()  # Code doesn't actually look exactly like this 

root.mainloop()
```

and I want there to be a delay between each rectangle being drawn. I have gathered that I should be doing:

```
def draw(*args):
    canvas.create_rectangle(xpos, ypos, xpos+10, ypos+10, fill=rgb_colour)

for item in sorted_list:
    root.after(10, draw)
```

However I cannot do this because my original for loop is nested within a function that contains the xpos, ypos, and colour variables, so  a new function to create the rectangle would lack the required variables. I realise I could solve this by nesting my entire function within a class, and then calling the variables from the class, however I want to keep this code very simple and I was wondering if there was a way to delay the creation of rectangles without the use of a class?

Edit: This:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
delay = 100

def draw_all(*args):
    global delay
    x, y = 0, 10
    for item in items:
        canvas.after(delay, canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill="red"))
        delay += 10
        x += 10

root.bind('<Return>', draw_all)
root.mainloop()
```

still returns an AttributeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a function that takes a list of items along with any other data it needs, pops one item from the list and creates the rectangle, and then calls itself until there are no more items.

```
def draw_one(items):
    item = items.pop()
    canvas.create_rectangle(...)
    if len(items) > 0:
        canvas.after(10, draw_one, items)
```

If you prefer to not use a function that calls itself, simply call the `create_rectangle` method using `after`:

```
def draw_all():
    delay = 0
    for item in items:
        canvas.after(delay, canvas.create_rectangle, x0, y0, x1, y1, ...)
        delay += 10
```

With that, the first will be drawn immediately, the next in 10ms, the next in 20ms, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I couldn't get your second example to work, I get a `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'`, any idea as to why? I'll edit my main post to include my entire test code.

Comment: @BenWo: You're using `after` wrong. Take a closer look at how I use it. (don't use `create_rectangle(...)`.)

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I could miss that, I have one more follow-up question, seeing as this method seemingly only accepts coordinates for the rectangle, how would I go about adding a fill colour?

Comment: @BenWo: the best solution is to write your own helper function which can accept positional arguments, since you can't pass keyword arguments via `after`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.